# HTML or javascript: upload folder to server

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, flash

I need to develop a web page where user can select a local folder to upload (incl. all sub-folders).

Nice-to-haves are:

- Only *.txt and *.xml files are automatically filtered and uploaded
- Once folder is chosen, web page is updated with list of files and/or number of files

On the server-side I run Tomcat (JSP / servlets), but this is probably not relevant for the question.

So far my best guess is to use HTML5:

```
<input type="file" name="file_input[]" id="file_input" multiple="" webkitdirectory="">
```

While this works nice with Chrome, it doesn't work with IE11 and Firefox (for these browsers you can only select multiple files to upload, but not a complete folder).

Any help / hint would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: This has been asked before, see stackoverflow.com/questions/9518335/select-directory-for-html5-multiple-file-input-in-firefox

Comment: Sorry, only possible in Chrome and more recent versions of Opera.